# Computing the differential of this map

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let:

$G = SL(2;\mathbb{R}) = \{ (a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \ \vert \ ad-bc=1 \}$, $V=\mathbb{R}^3$, and $F:G \to \mathfrak{g}^*$ defined by:

$$F(a,b,c,d)=(\frac{d^2}{4}, -\frac{c^2}{4}, \frac{cd}{4}  ) $$

with respect to a particular basis on $\mathfrak{g}^*$ (the one that arises from the Kiling form on $\mathfrak{g}$ and a particular basis $X,Y,Z$ on $\mathfrak{g}$). This gives rise a map:

$$dF_e: T_eG = \mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{sl}(2; \mathbb{R}) = \{ (a,b,c,-a) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \} \to T_{(0,1,0)} \mathfrak{g}^* \cong \mathfrak{g}^* $$
defined by:

$$dF_e(v)(f) = v(f \circ F), \ f:V \to \mathbb{R}, \ v \in \mathfrak{sl}(2; \mathbb{R}) $$

I would like to compute a formula or some such thing for $dF_e$, ie. given $X \in \mathfrak{sl}(2; \mathbb{R})$ what is $dF_e(X) \in \mathfrak{g}^*$ with respect to the basis above?

It has been suggested to me to use a decompostion on $G$ writing $g=kan$ (possibly the Iwasawa decomposition of $G$ but not necessarily), but I am unsure how this would be helpful. Is there a particular choice of coordinate chart near $e \in G$ that would lead to the Jacobian matrix of the differential being with respect to my basis? If it helps, the chosen basis on $\mathfrak{g}$ is:

$$X = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}, Y = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0  \end{bmatrix}, Z = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1  \end{bmatrix} $$

A guiding step in the right direction would very much be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we should start by computing 
$$dF_e(X) = \frac d{dt}\Big|_{t=0} F(\exp tX) = \frac d{dt}\Big|_{t=0} F\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & t\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\right) = \frac d{dt}\Big|_{t=0} \big(\frac14,0,0\big)=0,$$
assuming your coordinates on $SL(2;\Bbb R)$ are $\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$.

Can you do the other two?

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it was extremely helpful! To clarify:

$dF_e(Y) = \frac d{dt}\Big|_{t=0} F(\exp tY) = \frac d{dt}\Big|_{t=0} F\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ t & 1 \end{bmatrix}\right) = \frac d{dt}\Big|_{t=0} \big(\frac14,-\frac{t^2}{4}, \frac{t}{4} \big)= (0, 0, \frac14) $

$dF_e(Z) = \frac d{dt}\Big|_{t=0} F(\exp tZ) = \frac d{dt}\Big|_{t=0} F\left(\begin{bmatrix} e^t & 0\\ 0 & e^{-t} \end{bmatrix}\right) = \frac d{dt}\Big|_{t=0} \big( \frac{(e^{-t})^2}{4},0, 0 \big)= (-\frac12,0,0) $

is this right?

Comment: Ah yes right, edited to update, thank you so much.

Comment: You're most welcome :)

Comment: @Math: If you're satisfied with the answer, please accept it ... so that the question will go off the "unanswered" list. If you're not satisfied, let's proceed :)